# Creating Silverlight Overlay User Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm creating a silverlight user control that will display a transparent overlay with text over whatever xaml is contained if a property is set to true. So for example:

```
<my:Overlay Message="You don't have access to this feature." ShowOverlay="{Binding IsFeatureAvailable}">

<TextBox />
<Button Content="Search" />

</my:Overlay>
```

What I'm not quite sure about is how to implement the ability to put arbitrary xaml inside my user control, like above.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit your `OverlayControl` from `ContentControl`. Your template would look something like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Overlay" Background="#30000000">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Message}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<Grid>
<my:Overlay Message="You don't have access to this feature." ShowOverlay="{Binding IsFeatureAvailable}"/>

<TextBox />
<Button Content="Search" />

</Grid>
```

Also you can derrive you Overly control from ContentControl, and put content and OverLay layer in grid like shown above